# Email Attachments to SharePoint Document Library - Error

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have this weird problem when I try to use a simple default [flow template](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-US/templates/details/f7a46809e53c42108034e56acf83bb79/save-my-email-attachments-to-a-sharepoint-document-library/) to save email attachments to the company main SharePoint site: **company.sharepoint.com** (not subsite).

So I get started, by taking all the defaults of this flow, however, once i get to the point of providing the site address and document library path I get the error highlighted in red.

[image]

Where I get confused is that when I create a subsite like **company.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite** I enter the subsite address and the folder path automatically populates the folder structure for me to pick where I want to save such attachment.

I have given full owner permission to this test account with same results. So permission is not the problem.

**My question is, could it be I'm using the wrong flow to save to a main SharePoint site? or this is something not allowed?**

Comment: Just to double check. What connection are you using in the settings of that action? Your own account or the one of the test account? And are you able to upload a file with the same account in the root site manually via the interface?

Comment: @Expiscornovus I'm using the test account. After looking at the sharepoint admin center, the company.sharepoint.com is a Team Site "(classic Experience)" whereas the site everything works on is company.sharepoint.com/site/teamsite - "Team Site" 
our comapany.sharepoint.com is our landing page so not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: Are you site collection admin or do you have full control in the company.sharepoint.com site collection with the test account?

Comment: @Expiscornovus This account is not a site collector. I didn't think users with access would need to be site collector to be able to create PowerAutomate flows. Let me try that to see if that fixes the problem. 

I did noticed that the site with issues is marked as Team Site (Classic Experience) and it can also pose an issue. I will try adding the test account to the site collection account and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the connector and recreate a new connection to SharePoint.

In many cases, an error code of 403 appears in a flow fail because of an authentication error. If you have this type of error, you can usually fix an authentication error by updating the connection, please make sure you have update the connection.

You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/fix-flow-failures).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has a similar problem, the account to which you are creating a power automate flow must be a site collector to the root SharePoint site.